# How to play given notes on the guitar

Tags: guitar, notation

I'm sorry, if my question is not too generic, but I'm having trouble playing instrumental acoustic peace and would appreciate if you could help me out.

Here are the notes I have (sorry for scan quality):

[image: c major]

But I cannot figure out how to play them on guitar. C note should be heard throughout the bar and you should be able to hammer-on or pull-of from E to D. Can anyone think of a tab for this notation puzzle?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here are two possible solutions.

Option 1 - starting with the third finger on the 6th string, 8th fret. (that last B could be played with the first finger depending on where you want to go next.)  Generally in the fret 5 - fret 9 area.
[image: Possible solution 2]

Option 2 2 - solidly in the 7th position.  Starting with the second finger on the 6th string, 8th fret.  (You have to slide your first finger back one fret to get the last note.)  Feels a little easier to play (to me).
[image: Possible solution 1]

I'm sure there are other possibilities.  Of course, the solution you choose will depend on what came before and what is coming after this measure.

Comment: What tool did you use for your images? Can it do Roman Numerals for positions? Circled numbers for strings?

Comment: I used http://lilypond.org/ Yes it can do Roman Numerals for positions. I think circled strings are possible, but may require jumping through some hoops.  Lilypond isn't for everyone as you must use text markup to produce the notation - however, I think there is a GUI front for it.